# MFC dialog close issues

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog

Good day!
I have an MFC dialog with progress.
Dialog automatically closes after reaching 100% using PostMessageW(WM_CLOSE).
The problem is, when, during progress, I'm moving dialog over the screen, dialog is not closing and WM_CLOSE message is ignored. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You mean that if you keep moving the dialog using your mouse for a long time and the progress finishes, the dialog doesn't close until you release the mouse?

Comment: The dialog doesn't close even when I release the mouse button. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a modal dialog you shouldn't really need to use a `WM_CLOSE` message.

Normally you'd use the OK or Cancel button events to close it, call the `EndDialog` method from functional code or just return when your processing is complete (assuming that its the process run as soon as the dialog is initialised). You can set your return value at the same time e.g. `EndDialog(2);`.

Either way the dialog will close once th current message handler returns, so there could well be a delay, in closure but it shouldn't be much.

Comment: After running into the trap that you cant call EndDialog from a WM_KICKIDLE handler i now always use WM_CLOSE to close modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the activity behind progress bar done in a separate thread? It look like to be the case otherwise when you drag the dialog the progress bar would have froze until you release the dialog than it would have resumed. This means you might have to look into inter thread communication, how the message is being posted to the dialog HWND.

It might have to do with the dialog being in freeze (no activity) state while you are dragging it which seems to be normal windows behavior. If that is the case you could use signals/CEvent to tell the dialog to close down.